# How can i use multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading

Can you help me in `multithreading` for example how can i make this method works in two threads.

```
/**
     * returns 16 bytes
     */
    private byte[] keyStream() {
        nextState();
        final byte[] s = new byte[16];
        /* unroll */
        int x = X[6] ^ X[3] >>> 16 ^ X[1] << 16;
        s[0] = (byte) (x >>> 24);
        s[1] = (byte) (x >> 16);
        s[2] = (byte) (x >> 8);
        s[3] = (byte) x;
        x = X[4] ^ X[1] >>> 16 ^ X[7] << 16;
        s[4] = (byte) (x >>> 24);
        s[5] = (byte) (x >> 16);
        s[6] = (byte) (x >> 8);
        s[7] = (byte) x;
        x = X[2] ^ X[7] >>> 16 ^ X[5] << 16;
        s[8] = (byte) (x >>> 24);
        s[9] = (byte) (x >> 16);
        s[10] = (byte) (x >> 8);
        s[11] = (byte) x;
        x = X[0] ^ X[5] >>> 16 ^ X[3] << 16;
        s[12] = (byte) (x >>> 24);
        s[13] = (byte) (x >> 16);
        s[14] = (byte) (x >> 8);
        s[15] = (byte) x;
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: For Java or c# be specific?

Comment: Why would you want to multithread this?

Comment: @JunaidHassan: There is `final`, so java

Comment: If you use multiple threads it will be slower and much more complicated.  DO you not care about either of these?

Comment: I assume you are aware there is some significant bugs in the code sample.

Comment: You can use ByteBuffer to make it faster, but I would fix the bugs first.

Comment: `^` has higher precedence than `>>>` or `<<` so `int x = X[6] ^ X[3] >>> 16 ^ X[1] << 16;` is actually `int x = (X[6] ^ X[3]) >>> (16 ^ X[1]) << 16;` and this doesn't appear to be what you intended.

Comment: 1-"Junaid Hassan"It is JAVA language.                                             2-"leppie"because my project is enhancement for Rabbit StreamCipher algorithm, it works in sequential way SO i will improve it and make it faster by multithreading. It has many methods that we decided to make them in many threads which allow it to work together in same time. HERE i gave you only one method because i studied how to make threads but i got confused when i tried to apply it on my project.I hope that i could gave a good rough idea.

Comment: 3-"Peter Lawery" Of course i care about that because i use multithreading to make it faster.Do you want me send you the algorithm?                                                            THANK you so much for every one want to help me.

Comment: `to make it faster` - I would recommend to measure the performance gain after you implemented threading. I have seen a lot of attempts to make things faster ending up in actually making things slower. This one sounds like a good candidate to me - unless you are going to call this method with *independent* data multiple times, I'm not so sure if threading will help much. And by multiple, I mean numbers with at least three or four digits.

Comment: @Junaid Hassan It is JAVA language

Comment: @leppie because my project is enhancement for Rabbit StreamCipher algorithm, it works in sequential way SO i will improve it and make it faster by multithreading. It has many methods that we decided to make them in many threads which allow it to work together in same time. HERE i gave you only one method because i studied how to make threads but i got confused when i tried to apply it on my project.I hope that i could gave you a good rough idea.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Of course i care about that because i use multithreading to make it faster.Do you want me send you the algorithm? THANK you so much for every one want to help me.

Comment: @JensG yes of course i will compare the time before and after multithreading BUT my problem is that i'm new in multithreading and i need a help from any one knows about multithreading

Comment: No, your real problem is that you have a tool which you know you can't handle (today) but still believe it will solve your problem. That dog don't hunt, usually. You will first have to learn to use the tool, the advantages and pitfalls and traps, when to apply and when not. Nevertheless, applying threading to this problem will be a good opportunity to make your first steps on the road to aquire that knowledge.

Comment: The problem you have is that you have code which should take about 100 ns.  The most expensive bit is the object array creation.  Passing a task to another thread might take 10,000 ns (and means creating more objects)  Unless you have a significant piece of work, adding threads can make your code dramatically slower i.e around 100x slower in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply make a class, implementing `Runnable` and override `run` function, like this:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        byte[] retVal = keyStream();
    }
    /**
     * returns 16 bytes
     */
    private byte[] keyStream() {
        // function implementation
    }
}
```

and you can use it in some ways, such as this way:

```
Thread myThread1= new Thread(new MyRunnable());
Thread myThread2= new Thread(new MyRunnable());
myThread1.start();
myThread2.start();
```

Comment: Never extend `Thread`, but implement `Runnable`. These then can be passed to a thread, or to an executor service, or to whatever.

Comment: So you can choose my answer as the correct one :) @Yusra

Comment: Hello @saeed thank you so much for helping. BUT could you please explain that to me because i'm new in multithreading but i knew the basics such as: implement Runnable interface then override run method then made an instance from class then pass it in the thread constructor finally we can call the methods from thread class BUT my problem is what have i do inside run method because i have many methods more than this one

Comment: So add more details. Your question isn't detailed enough